# OpenGLES20 - Rotation matrix screws movements - rotate view matrix with angles instead?

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, opengl-es-2.0

Current state:

Creating the frustum, saved in `mViewMatrix`, also I have both a quaternion `q`, a float array of three angles (yaw, roll, pitch e.g.) as well as a rotation matrix `mRotationMatrix` - representing the quaternion as well as the angles' rotation.

What I want to achieve is some sort of an augmented reality effect. I'm currently applying the `mRotationMatrix` to the `mViewMatrix`:

```
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mTmpMatrix, 0, // mViewMatrix
            mCameraPosition[0], mCameraPosition[1], mCameraPosition[2], // eye
            mTargetRotPosition[0], mTargetRotPosition[1], mTargetRotPosition[2],
            0, 1, 0); // up

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mViewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mTmpMatrix, 0);
```

This handles the whole rotation, up vector as well, so the rotation works fine. But since the rotation matrix comes from the device's sensors, the rotation matrix is kind of around the wrong axis.

As a reference, this image should help:

[image]

Scenario #1:
Yaw: pointing towards north, it's 0.
Pitch: 0
Roll: 0

Camera is looking to the right, but y is correct.

If I now increase pitch, i.e. pick up the device, the camera now moves to the right, instead of looking up.

If I increase yaw, camera is moving up, instead of to the right.

If I increase roll, weird transformations happen.

In the video, I'm executing the movements in this order. The compass is also showing correct movements, just the transformations of the OpenGL camera are screwed.

Video: [Sample screenrecord video](http://de.tinypic.com/r/14c5hjb/8)

Currently, I'm using the following code to get the rotation matrix, as well as pitch/roll/yaw:

```
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                mRemappedXAxis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;
                mRemappedYAxis = SensorManager.AXIS_Z;
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                mRemappedXAxis = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
                mRemappedYAxis = SensorManager.AXIS_Y;
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                mRemappedXAxis = SensorManager.AXIS_Y;
                mRemappedYAxis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z;
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                mRemappedXAxis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X;
                mRemappedYAxis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;
                break;
        }

        float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
        float[] correctedRotationMatrix = new float[16];
        float[] rotationVector = new float[]{x, y, z}; // from sensor fusion
        float[] orientationVals = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, rotationVector);
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, mRemappedXAxis, mRemappedYAxis, correctedRotationMatrix);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(correctedRotationMatrix, orientationVals);
```

I've already tried some other remap-combinations, but none of them seemed to change anything in the movement-translation..

My other thought would be to rotate the vectors I'm using in setLookAtM by myself. But I don't know how I am supposed to work with the up vector.

If someone could either show me / point me in the direction how to handle the rotation, that the movements I execute will be parsed right, or else how I am supposed to do this with the bare angles in OpenGL, I'd be thankful.

Comment: I also faced a similar problem recently.

When i rotated the objects by touching the screen, the axes of rotation rotated too.And now the rotations would be weird. 

If this is what your problem is..i can tell u how i fixed this.

Is this the issue?

Comment: Your idea of remapping the x,y,z vectors from the device reference frame to your app reference frame is the right one. Instead of swapping the vectors experimentally I suggest you draw both reference frames and calculate the rotation from one to the other. Then simply multiply the device readings by the matrix to get them in your app reference frame.

Comment: @umerbanday Im not sure, but I'd be glad if you could post your solution, allowing me to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , i used to calculate the incremental rotation delta(angle) every time the finger moved on the screen. From this incremental rotation angle, i created a temporary rotation matrix. Then, i post multiplied my overall rotation matrix(Historical rotation matrix with all the previous incremental rotations) with this and finally used this overall rotation matrix in my draw method.

The problem was that i was POST MULTIPLYING the incremental rotation with my overall rotation which meant... my latest rotation would be applied to the object first and the oldest(first) rotation would be applied last.

This is what messed up everything.

The solution was simple, instead of post multiplying, i pre-multiplied the incremental rotation with my overall rotation matrix.My rotations were now in right order and everything worked fine.

Hope this helps.

Here is where i learnt it from.Check this question.
"9.070 How do I transform my objects around a fixed coordinate system rather than the object's local coordinate system?"
http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm#tran0162

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm not sure if this would be the solution, since I'm not rotating the objects themself but instead the view matrix, and I don't rotate it "again" - I always take the default view matrix from my lookAt function and rotate it with the given rotation matrix. If I understand the link correctly, this should only happen if I rotate an object, and save the rotated matrix - and try to rotate it again?

Comment: Well it is recommended to use incremental rotations because in case of calculating the whole rotation everytime,the order of rotations(like along x..then along y..etc) may mess things up.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion, how I could do this, as I only get the quaternion/rotation matrix of the whole device-rotation?